# Having issue with DOM selection in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="text"></p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="text"></p>
    <img></img>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="text"></p>
    <div class="vid"></div>
</div>
```

Assume above is a list of users' post, and I want to identify type of post of them. To select the image or video type is easy, for example the video, just select like $('.wrapper .vid').

But there is a problem when I want to select plaintext type of post, because the `class text` also appear in vid and image type of post.

Comment: Try some `$('.wrapper').filter(…)`

Comment: @Bergi can provide answer?

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact criteria for "plaintext post". Does it mean that the only child element is a `p.text`? Or does it mean that there is neither a `div.vid` nor a `img` descendant (direct child)? You decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want `wrapper` elements which does not hae `vid` or `img` then

```
$('.wrapper').not(':has(img, .vid)')
```

If you want the `text` elements within them

```
$('.wrapper').not(':has(img, .vid)').find('.text')
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to return the `.text`. So, it should be `$('.text', $('.wrapper').not(':has(img, .vid)'))`

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos No I did not want to return it, just to determine which type of post is the wrapper. so $('.wrapper').not(':has(img, .vid)')
 will do right?

Comment: @user3522926 that will return all `wrapper` elements which does not have an `img` or `vid` elements

Comment: @user3522926 If you consider a text post a `.wrapper` without `img` or `.vid` elements, then yes, this answer from Arun should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to get the three different types of posts. Something like this:

```
var $textPosts = $('.wrapper').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('img, .vid').length == 0;
});

var $imgPosts = $('.wrapper').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('img').length > 0;
});

var $vidPosts = $('.wrapper').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('.vid').length > 0;
});
```

Also note that the `img` HTML tag is self closing, eg:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" title="Foo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get this right that you want to get all the test in `<p>` with the class text, then you can do something like this

```
$('.wrapper > .text').html()
```

The above code will give you the content of only those element with class "text" that are direct under class "wrapper"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` to filter out the element with class `text` whose has no sibling:

```
var text = $('.text').filter(function() {
    return $(this).siblings('*').length == 0
}).text();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tdey8du1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  $('.wrapper p.text').text()
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AnkitaPalekar/15s9zeLy/)